# Unattended Net-install Ubuntu over Wifi with user-supplied network info

Tags: ubuntu, unattended, netinstall

Is there a way to change the Ubuntu Ubiquity installation to not continue without an internet connection?

I have created a preseed file that automated the entire installation process including assigning the wep key using the string

```
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep <wep_key>
```

The problem i am facing is i would like the installation to stop at the "Select a Wireless Network" screen if the autmoatically configured network connection doesn't work, instead of trying to continue with the installation.  Also, how do you remove the "I don't want to connect to a wifi network right now" option seen below?

[image]

(Image is from the website http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

I have tried the Ubuntu Customization Kit but im not finding where i can have this level of control.

Comment: This question is overly broad. Please edit in the specific problem you are facing and Flag to have it re-opened. Thank you.

Comment: You may get a better answer to this question on [ubuntu.SE] -- I know what I've described below will work (because I routinely hack the Ubiquity installer in this way) but I'm not certain it's the officially-blessed way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you would need to manually edit the `ubiquity` installer scripts.

These are located in `/usr/lib/ubiquity`, and are typically owned by the `ubiquity` package, so if you intend to customize them you will probably want to roll your own variant of that package.

I believe the one you want to edit is `/usr/lib/ubiquity/netcfg/netcfg` which is actually a compiled binary, so you will need to download the Ubiquity source package to customize and rebuilt it (or replace it with something you write on your own).

Comment: According to [UbiquityAutomation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation), ubiquity ignores any `netcfg` commands. (Though on my install it at least executes `netcfg/get_hostname`)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question but if anyone runs into this, here's the info: The wifi screen won't show when you have set **automatic-ubiquity** in grub.cfg. To hack it and make it show, you need to unpack the Ubuntu image (I used 20.04.3) using the LiveCDCustomization instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization just up to the **Extract the Desktop System** step.

After that, the Live CD file system will be in the ./edit folder. Use your favorite text editor to edit ./edit/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-wireless.py file and comment out these 3 lines (in 20.04.3 they are lines 67-69):

```
#if self.is_automatic:
#    self.page = None
#    return
```

Those lines tell it to skip showing the WiFi connection screen when the setup is set to automatic.